# Push changes via the shopify API

Tags: shopify

I've been looking over the Shopify API, and I've seen some really cool RESTful APIs to get data when queried, but I've been looking for an application, service, API or some kind of plugin that will push data changes of current products somehow: through a post, soap call, or anything really. Does something like that exist? I've looked around a bit, but haven't been able to find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for webhooks. Basically you can register to receive POST requests to a given endpoint for a particular topic.

Here's our technical documentation: http://api.shopify.com/webhook.html

And here's a guide: http://wiki.shopify.com/WebHook

Comment: Thanks David, that works perfect. Can't believe I skipped over it actually.